# Base R library not loading in VS

Tags: c#, r, r.net, rtvs

**Situation**: I have installed R 3.3 and set up R for Visual Studio extension.

**Code snippet**:

```
 log.ir <- log(iris[, 1:4])
 ir.species <- iris[, 5]
 ir.pca <- stats:::prcomp(log.ir, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

This works in R interactive window in Visual Studio, it also work in RGui but when I run it using C# the code fails on 3rd line:

```
engine.Evaluate("log.ir <- log(iris[, 1:4])");
engine.Evaluate("ir.species <- iris[, 5]");
engine.Evaluate("ir.pca <- stats:::prcomp(log.ir, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)");
```

**Exception**:

*Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.*

[image: Visual Studio error running R code]

I have tried reinstalling all R components but it hasn't helped. And obviously I have checked and the stats.dll file exists in the path specified in the error.

**RTVS version**:
[image]

Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Are you really using RTVS? If so could you post a screen shot of the About dialog box, scrolled down so we can see the RTVS (R Tools for Visual Studio) version, and the rest.

Comment: @MikeWise updated the question with additional info.

Comment: So you are using rdotnet and RTVS both. Interesting. I had no idea rdotnet even existed :)

Comment: RTVS is only a client for R. Rdotnet allows you to use it in C#...

Comment: Yes, I will look into it once I get something else finished. Probably be tomorrow. But you should mention that you have installed both of these R platforms in your "Situation:" above. I see them both in your tags, so that is okay.

Comment: No problem. I kinda got this feeling its got to do with bit-ness, but not sure how because R and its libraries are 64bit

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this recently and the solution to this seems to be relatively straightforward. All you need to do is add the path to the R.dll from the relevant architecture (i386/x64)to the System Path statement. So, on my system I added "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\i386" to the System Path Environment Variable. I also forced the architecture to x86, but that could just be overkill.

This information was gleaned from [ASP.NET with R.NET](http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/tut_asp_dot_net/)

Answer (score 1):

I have been in same problem like you. I could not to load my base `R` `dll` functions. After two days of researching finally I found one question solving my problem:

https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet/issues/62

Solution is very easy: in `R-3.4.3` does not work properly reading path to your `R` folder, you can use `R-3.4.2` and wait for correction in new `R` version :D - or rewrite `R_Home` environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

This was the correct solution for me after my computer crashed and I had to reload everything. Between the time I had developed 3 new programs and the time of the crash, R-3.4.3 came out and the new version did not work with my programs. I used the CRAN "Time Machine" and reinstalled an earlier version and everything worked just fine.